# Procedure entry point sqlite3_db_filname could not be located in the dll

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am developing an application using "wxWidgets" and "wxSqlite". The following error appears, when I execute the application. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears it wants to load a function that is not exported by the DLL.
What code tries to call that function? Is it yours or some framework-code?

- If it's your code, check for typos and maybe use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify that the function is exported by the DLL.
- If the function is called by third-party code, verify that you set up this component properly.

Comment: I would agree, it would appear that the import library that you used when you linked the project is incompatible with the DLL on the installed DLL.